# Should a question about a Sci-Fi Movie/TV Show be asked in "Science Fiction & Fantasy" or "Movies & TV"?

Tags: discussion

I'm not sure if there is a subsite to ask about Stack Exchange itself.

If I have a question about a Sci-Fi movie or TV show, is it better to ask this question here or under the Movies & TV subsite?